# Numpy function not differentiating between dot product and matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

For example, I have an equation for projection matrix which works for 1 dimensional vectors:

[image]

where P is projection matrix and T is transpose.

We know that we can't simplify this fraction more (by cancelling terms) since denominator is a dot product (thus 0 dimensional scalar, number) and numerator is a matrix (column multiplied by row is a matrix).

I'm not sure how could I define function for this equation in numpy, considering that the current function that I'm using does not differentiate between these  terms, multiplication is treated as it has commutative property. I'm using `numpy.multiply` method:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array(a)
>>> a*a.T
array([1, 4, 9])
>>> a.T*a  
array([1, 4, 9])
```

As you see, both of them output vectors.

I've also tried using `numpy.matmul` method:

```
>>> np.matmul(a, a.T)
14
>>> np.matmul(a.T, a)
14
```

which gives dot product for both of the function calls.

I also did try `numpy.dot` but it obviously doesn't work for numerator terms.

From my understanding, the first function call should output matrix (since column is multiplied by row) and the second function call should output a scalar in a proper case.

Am I mistaken? Is there any method that differentiates between **a** multiplied by **a** transpose and **a** transpose multiplied by **a**?

Thank you!

Comment: the * operator is not the dot product

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html

Comment: @talonmies Yes, which function can be used to differentiate between a^Ta and aa^T? Is there any "universal" multiplication function? Thanks!

Comment: @Chrispresso Tried dot product method as well, but it doesn't work for terms in numerator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 1-dimensional numpy arrays *are not* column vectors (and operations such as transposition do not make sense). If you want to obtain a column vector you should define your array as a 2-dimensional array (with the second dimension size equal to 1).

However, you don't need to define a column vector, as numpy offers functions to do what you want by manipulating an 1D array as follows

`P = np.outer(a,a)/np.inner(a,a)`

Answer (score 2):

Stelios' answer is the best, no doubt but for completeness you can use the `@` operator with 2-d arrays:

```
a = np.array([1,4,9])[np.newaxis]

P = (a.T @ a) / (a @ a.T)
```

Comment: Thank you. That helped me a lot as well, was looking for proper 2D solution.